# How to find SHA-1 key (for firebase) in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

today i wanted to create a database but i needed a SHA-1 key. I've had some oddities with Gradle
(i needed Android[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt1bK.png)->Tasks->android->signingReport)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMxj7.png)

Comment: Please tell the version of android studio you are using

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to File
2. Settings
3. Experimental
4. Unchecked the 'Do not build gradle task list during gradle sync' and click 'OK'
5. Go to file
6. Sync project with Gradle files

Now you will see the signing report option on right side in gradle tab. if not then restart android studio and that's all.
[image]